# How to properly filter MDX Measures

Tags: sql-server, multidimensional-array, ssas, mdx, cube

I currently have an MDX query that returns accurate results given a date range and office.

```
 SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[%Denial Rate] } ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( [Date - Remit Received].[Date Key].&[20210201] : [Date - Remit Received].[Date Key].&[20220131] ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Office ID].&[9] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM [Remit])) WHERE ( [Office ID].&[9] )
```

The following code is how [Measures].[%Denial Rate] is calculated

```
(([Measures].[Distinct Claim Count_hd], [Denied Claim].[Denied Claim].&[Yes])/[Measures].[Distinct Claim Count_hd])
```

The following MDX query is using the elements used to calculate the [Measures].[%Denial Rate] in the above query.

```
with  
            Set Denial_y1 as
           {([Denied Claim].[Denied Claim].&[Yes],[Date - Remit Received].[DateKey].[DateKey].&[202101]:[Date - Remit Received].[DateKey].[DateKey].&[20211231])}
            
           set ClaimDetail_all1 as
           {([Date - Remit Received].[Date - Remit Received].[DateKey].[DateKey].&[202101]:[Date - Remit Received].[DateKey].[DateKey].&[20211231])}
            
           Member [Measures].[(%Denial Rate_hd,Year 2021)] as
           sum(Denial_y1,Measures.[Distinct Claim Count_hd])/sum(ClaimDetail_all1,Measures.[Distinct Claim Count_hd])
            
        
           Set Denial_y2 as
           {([Denied Claim].[Denied Claim].&[Yes],[Date - Remit Received].[DateKey].[DateKey].&[202101]:[Date - Remit Received].[DateKey].[DateKey].&[20211231])}
        
          
          set ClaimDetail_all2 as
           {([Date - Remit Received].[DateKey].[DateKey].&[202101]:[Date - Remit Received].[DateKey].[DateKey].&[20211231])}
          
          Member [Measures].[(%Denial Rate_hd,Year 2022)] as
          sum(Denial_y2,Measures.[Distinct Claim Count_hd])/sum(ClaimDetail_all2 ,Measures.[Distinct Claim Count_hd])
          
          Select {[Measures].[(%Denial Rate_hd,Year 2021)],[Measures].[(%Denial Rate_hd,Year 2022)] } on 0
          from Remit
          where({[Office ID].[9]} )
```

They only reason I am using the syntax in the second query is because I need to return results for multiple date ranges. This is how I understand the cube working: in the first query it basically looks at the sets filtered in the where statement and returns the appropriate number for that measure based on that range. In the second query it makes a set based on dateKey(a numerical version of date where 20210101 is equivalent of 2021-01-01) and [Denied Claim].[Denied Claim].&[Yes], then summing the Measures.[Distinct Claim Count_hd] with the set created on Date Key.

Here is the rub,  because the [Distinct Claim Count_hd] measure counts distinct figures from the input table based on [Date Key] it counts distinct claims for each date in the date range and then sums them. If you did a distinct count for 1 year(and not 365 days) the number is lower because the duplicate figures will show up on different days.

However, in the first query it is able to return %Denial Rate (a calculation based on [Distinct Claim Count_hd]) from a datekey range that is set in the where clause. In short, Is there a way to return more than one date range in a single select statement using the first query, or is there a way to use the syntax from the second query where the date range and measure interact the same way that the measure and date range interact in the first query? Or is there another option that I haven't thought of?

Perhaps a clearer way to see this issue is the following queries. The first returns a count of  43546

```
with 
   set fiscalyear as
  [Date - Remit Received].[Date Key].[Date Key].&[20210101]:[Date - Remit Received].[Date Key].[Date Key].&[20211231]

  Member [Measures].total_claim_count as
  sum(fiscalyear,[Measures].[Distinct Claim Count_hd]) 
  
  select [Measures].total_claim_count  on 0
  FROM [Remit]
  WHERE ([Office ID].[9])
```

The second query returns 43525

```
  select [Measures].[Distinct Claim Count_hd] on 0
    FROM [Remit]
  WHERE ([Office ID].[9],[Date - Remit Received].[Date Key].[Date Key].&[20210101]:[Date - Remit Received].[Date Key].[Date Key].&[20211231])
```

Is there a way to create a set before the select statement(like in the first query) where the date range functions like the where statement in the second query?

Answer (score 0):

"Is there a way to create a set before the select statement(like in the first query) where the date range functions like the where statement in the second query?"

Yes, you could transfer that expression from the `WHERE` clause to a `WITH` clause by using `NONEMPTY`:

```
WITH 
  SET [SOMEDATES] AS 
    NonEmpty
    (
        [Date - Remit Received].[Date Key].[Date Key].&[20210101]
      : 
        [Date - Remit Received].[Date Key].[Date Key].&[20211231]
     ,[Office ID].[9]
    ) 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Distinct Claim Count_hd] ON 0
FROM [Remit]
WHERE 
  [SOMEDATES];
```